# How to deserialize xml from the second node

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I would like to deserialize part of xml, I tried this, but it does not work.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test), new XmlRootAttribute("Test"));
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<Root1><Root2><Test><Id>5</Id></Test></Root2></Root1>")))
        {
            var test = serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }           
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public int Id;
}
```

How can I say to `XmlSerializer` to start serialization from `<Test>`?

Comment: Well, the *complex* answer would involve loading the DOM and navigating to the desired node, or using the xml-reader API and doing similar - both are kinda awkward; any reason you just just deserialize to `Root1` and just return `obj.Root2.Test` ? It'll probably be much less work...

Comment: Currently I am using your way, just want to know if `XmlSerializer` supports deserialization from the second/third etc node...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move to desired node with `XmlReader`.

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<Root1><Root2><Test><Id>5</Id></Test></Root2></Root1>")))
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
{
    reader.ReadToFollowing("Test");
    var test = (Test)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```